# Qcalendarwidget multiple selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I got a really dumb question for Qcalendarwidget. In the selection mode, we can set it as no selection or single selection, but is there any way to set it as multiple selections?  - like hold the ctrl and do multiple select date - return with me a list of dates

Comment: No. If you want that, you need to subclass it and implement it on your own, interfacing with its internal QTableView.